# How to use sendmail with SendGrid from Google Compute Engine?

Tags: email, sendmail, google-compute-engine, sendgrid

I have a simple website which runs with Joomla!, and it has a contact form from where the visitor can send a message to me. This message is sent by e-mail using the `sendmail` service.

The website machine is running inside Google Compute Engine, and by default I can't send e-mails from it (that's a restriction imposed by Google). To achieve the goal of sending e-mails, a 3rd-party service is needed, such as SendGrid.

I created a free account on SendGrid using the [Google Cloud partner program](https://sendgrid.com/partner/google), validated my user and so on. The account is properly provisioned.

I configured my `sendmail` service to use SendGrid to deliver the e-mails, according to [this tutorial](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Mail_Servers/sendmail.html). Everything seems to be ok, but... no message is delivered at all.

My mail log at `/var/log/mail.log` shows:

```
Jan 21 16:22:10 web-hosting sm-mta[16350]: t0JHWaec027559: to=<my@email.com>, delay=1+22:49:34, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=23251559, re
lay=smtp.sendgrid.net., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with smtp.sendgrid.net.
```

[According to Google](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/sending-mail), my machine can't use the ports `25`, `465` and `587`, so I changed the configuration to use the port `2525` in the `sendmail.mc` file. Nothing changed.

Any hints? My machine is running Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

Comment: Did you double-check that your account is sending emails? You can test it out via curl: `$ curl -d 'to=destination@example.com&amp;toname=Destination&amp;subject=Example Subject&amp;text=testingtextbody&amp;from=info@domain.com&amp;api_user=your_sendgrid_username&amp;api_key=your_sendgrid_password' https://api.sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json`

Comment: @heitortsergent Yes, when using the API directly I can send e-mails perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem.

My original `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` file don't have the `#dnl define(‘SMART_HOST’, ‘smtp.your.provider’)dnl` line, so I didn't know exactly where to put the configuration ([source](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Mail_Servers/sendmail.html)):

```
define(`SMART_HOST', `smtp.sendgrid.net')dnl
FEATURE(`access_db')dnl
define(`RELAY_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 2525')dnl
define(`ESMTP_MAILER_ARGS', `TCP $h 2525')dnl
```

(Note: for Google Compute Engine machines, you need to use the 2525 port instead of the default 587)

The thing is, **you can't put it at the end of the file**. The configuration started working when I put it just after the "DO NOT TOUCH HERE" section:

```
dnl # Items controlled by /etc/mail/sendmail.conf - DO NOT TOUCH HERE
...
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MSP-v4, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl
dnl # SendGrid code here
```