# How to manage emails with google compute engine

Tags: email, cloud, google-compute-engine, webmail

What I want : I want to move my websites from cpanel to Google Compute Engine (VM)

What I did : LAMP installed, and websites works like a charm, but there is a little problem.

What is my problem : EMAILS! In cPanel I have Email Accounts -  https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrYW4.png ,  but now how to manage emails.

What incoming IMAP mail server to complete in thunderbird mail - https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCDbe.png , ok outgoing I will pass the smtp.sendgird.com , but incoming? what server.

If I'm not clear, tell me and I will rewrite again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use sendmail with SendGrid from Google Compute Engine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072278/how-to-use-sendmail-with-sendgrid-from-google-compute-engine)

Answer (score 5):

Solved. Now I post the solution if someone has the same problem.

To receive mail, trick is to add at firewall rules in Google Compute Engine (at your instance) :

**your-rule-name 0.0.0.0/0 tcp:25** (port 25 is blocked by default).

And after that with simple mail server ex: iredmail, it will work to receive mails.

In Cloud DNS you must add mx like that if you install a mail server in same instance you have websites:

*| domain.com | | MX | | 300 | 0 mail.domain.com |*

**and**

*| mail.domain.com | | A | | 300 | | IP to your public server |*

And for sending mail (ex: sendgrid) a simple smtp edit in postfix in main.cf with tutorial from sendgrid : 
https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Mail_Servers/postfix.html

For IMAP in thunderbird for example you pass the mail.domain.com 143 port.
and in smtp smtp.sendgrid.net and edit in smtp login and password from sendgrid smtp.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

More accurate command to create the firewall rule.

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create incoming-email --allow tcp:25
```